# Convergence weak * (star) in a metric space $X$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space and $\{x^*_n\} \subseteq X^*$,$\{y_n\}\subseteq X$

a) if $\{x^*_n\} \rightharpoonup x ^*$ then $\{x^*_n\}$ is strongly bounded and $\|x^*\| \le \liminf ||x^*_n||$?

b) if $\{x^*_n\} \rightharpoonup x ^*$ and $\|y_n-y\|_X \to 0$ then $(y_n,x^*_n) \to (y,x^*)$?

My attempt:

a) $\{x^*_n\} \rightharpoonup x ^*\iff(x,x^*_n) \to (x,x^*) \quad \forall x \in X$

$\forall x \in X$ $|(x,x^*_n)|\le\|x^*_n||\,||x\|$

because $\{x^*_n\} \rightharpoonup x ^*$ then

$|(x,x^*)|=\lim_{n\to +\infty} |(x,x^*_n)|\le\liminf(\|x^*_n\|\,\|x\|)=(\liminf \|x^*_n\|)\|x\|$

so I have $\|x^*\|=\sup_{\|x^*\|=1}|(x,x^*)| \le \liminf \|x^*_n\|$?

and for b)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here,I shall denote linear functionals by $f$ and vectors by $v$.First of all, if $f_n$ converges in the weak$^{*}$ sense to $f$ then $f_n$ is uniformly bounded, as stated in the first part.Now say, $v_n$ converges to $v$ in norm.Then $|f_n(v_n) - f(v)|= |f_n(v_n)-f_n(v)+f_n(v)-f(v)| \leq ||f_n||.||v_n - v|| + |f_n(v) - f(v)| \leq M||v_n - v|| + |f_n(v)-f(v)|$ for some $M>0$.I could bound it above like this due to the uniform boundedness of $f_n$.Now the first term tends to zero due to norm convergence of $v_n$ and the second one tends to zero due to weak$^{*}$ convergence of $f_n$.

Comment: But using the notation that the prof gives us above?

Comment: It won't matter, you just need to replace all $f_n$ with $x_n^{*}$, $f$ with $x^{*}$ and $v_n$ with $y_n$ in the above proof.I wrote it like this simply because I am better accustomed and feel more comfortable with it,that's all.

Comment: The core idea is to write $x_n^{*}(y_n) - x^{*}(y)$ as $x_n^{*}(y_n) - x_n^{*}(y) + x_n^{*}(y) - x^{*}(y)$.After that, the rest pretty much falls in place, you just need to use triangle inequality.